# Gnuplot Heat Map from XYZ data file

Tags: gnuplot, heatmap

i'm having trouble with the plot of a heat map with gnuplot. I have this data file

```
0.0 40.0 778.78120008990152
0.0 50.0 821.24320411182714
0.0 60.0 857.79241694261157
0.0 70.0 890.06020449693267
0.0 80.0 919.06296578423655
0.0 90.0 945.48354694661066
0.0 100.0 969.80332391358638
0.0 110.0 992.37626201962348
0.0 120.0 1013.4707848548982

0.05 40.0 785.04802668734237
0.05 50.0 827.79005910832893
0.05 60.0 864.58649509875329
0.05 70.0 897.07636244554294
0.05 80.0 926.28161433212620
0.05 90.0 952.88868104300536
0.05 100.0 977.38301140737394
0.05 110.0 1000.1186127099754
0.05 120.0 1021.3660770787799

0.10 40.0 791.56182397211330
0.10 50.0 834.59556080405616
0.10 60.0 871.64949898510815
0.10 70.0 904.37004417201081
0.10 80.0 933.78677335142288
0.10 90.0 960.58855081404715
0.10 100.0 985.26351347238995
0.10 110.0 1008.1684300336018
0.10 120.0 1029.5754781163455

0.15 40.0 798.34055165487189
0.15 50.0 841.67824576244413
0.15 60.0 878.99958975502966
0.15 70.0 911.96168205893628
0.15 80.0 941.59893813600002
0.15 90.0 968.60362899084521
0.15 100.0 993.46744258593492
0.15 110.0 1016.5494213690502
0.15 120.0 1038.1233581496806

0.20 40.0 805.40555242206403
0.20 50.0 849.05987797369721
0.20 60.0 886.66147827497946
0.20 70.0 919.87499517151218
0.20 80.0 949.74215716287370
0.20 90.0 976.95914263993404
0.20 100.0 1002.0199820137157
0.20 110.0 1025.2868349030709
0.20 120.0 1047.0347386927497

0.25 40.0 812.77839951944816
0.25 50.0 856.76373305819050
0.25 60.0 894.65807150159071
0.25 70.0 928.13559296367407
0.25 80.0 958.24231762800366
0.25 90.0 985.68181901109608
0.25 100.0 1010.9489001030934
0.25 110.0 1034.4096229335219
0.25 120.0 1056.3396102939134

0.30 40.0 820.48532442240912
0.30 50.0 864.81721193165276
0.30 60.0 903.01793306626575
0.30 70.0 936.77143987457748
0.30 80.0 967.13070171686991
0.30 90.0 994.80260583578638
0.30 100.0 1020.2860583598051
0.30 110.0 1043.9491920105042
0.30 120.0 1066.0705495008092

0.35 40.0 828.55397604267148
0.35 50.0 873.24971731819551
0.35 60.0 911.77188280323685
0.35 70.0 945.81542098750799
0.35 80.0 976.43920139491001
0.35 90.0 1004.3551308142532
0.35 100.0 1030.0670096356569
0.35 110.0 1053.9431809276018
0.35 120.0 1076.2647985870872
```

and i'm using this comands for a contour line at 930

```
unset surface
set contour
set cntrparam levels discrete 930
set table
set out "e-nb-hierro.out"
splot "mapa-estabilidad.dat"
```

and then i use the following for the plot

```
unset table
set dgrid3d
set term pngcairo enhanced dashed color size 35cm,30cm font 'Arial, 28'
set output "Estabilidad.png"
set pm3d explicit
set pm3d map
set pm3d interpolate 0,0
set palette model RGB  defined ( 1.4 'black', 1.7 'blue', 2.0 'red', 2.1 'yellow')

set xlabel "{/Symbol a} [MeV]"
set ylabel "{/:Italic Bag} [MeV/fm^3]"
set cblabel "{/:Italic {{/Symbol e}/n_B }}[MeV]"

set size square

set xrange [0.0:0.35]
set yrange [40:120]
set mxtics 2
set mytics 2
set xtics 0.0,0.05,0.35

splot "mapa-estabilidad.dat" u 1:2:3 w pm3d not, "e-nb-hierro.out" u 1:2:3 w l lt 8 lw 3 lc 'white' not
```

this is what i get:

[image]

and i want something like this:

[image]

for the previous image i didn't use dgrid3d and worked fine, but in this case the terminal pop's out the message that i need a grid, so i left it there. Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without having fully understood why your script is not working, here is a slightly modified script which seems to get the desired result. So, the difference to your trial is:

- writing the contour line into a datablock (writing to a file should also be fine)
- unsetting contour and setting surface after writing to datablock
- not using `dgrid3d`

**Data:** `SO75041085.dat`

```
0.0 40.0 778.78120008990152
0.0 50.0 821.24320411182714
0.0 60.0 857.79241694261157
0.0 70.0 890.06020449693267
0.0 80.0 919.06296578423655
0.0 90.0 945.48354694661066
0.0 100.0 969.80332391358638
0.0 110.0 992.37626201962348
0.0 120.0 1013.4707848548982

0.05 40.0 785.04802668734237
0.05 50.0 827.79005910832893
0.05 60.0 864.58649509875329
0.05 70.0 897.07636244554294
0.05 80.0 926.28161433212620
0.05 90.0 952.88868104300536
0.05 100.0 977.38301140737394
0.05 110.0 1000.1186127099754
0.05 120.0 1021.3660770787799

0.10 40.0 791.56182397211330
0.10 50.0 834.59556080405616
0.10 60.0 871.64949898510815
0.10 70.0 904.37004417201081
0.10 80.0 933.78677335142288
0.10 90.0 960.58855081404715
0.10 100.0 985.26351347238995
0.10 110.0 1008.1684300336018
0.10 120.0 1029.5754781163455

0.15 40.0 798.34055165487189
0.15 50.0 841.67824576244413
0.15 60.0 878.99958975502966
0.15 70.0 911.96168205893628
0.15 80.0 941.59893813600002
0.15 90.0 968.60362899084521
0.15 100.0 993.46744258593492
0.15 110.0 1016.5494213690502
0.15 120.0 1038.1233581496806

0.20 40.0 805.40555242206403
0.20 50.0 849.05987797369721
0.20 60.0 886.66147827497946
0.20 70.0 919.87499517151218
0.20 80.0 949.74215716287370
0.20 90.0 976.95914263993404
0.20 100.0 1002.0199820137157
0.20 110.0 1025.2868349030709
0.20 120.0 1047.0347386927497

0.25 40.0 812.77839951944816
0.25 50.0 856.76373305819050
0.25 60.0 894.65807150159071
0.25 70.0 928.13559296367407
0.25 80.0 958.24231762800366
0.25 90.0 985.68181901109608
0.25 100.0 1010.9489001030934
0.25 110.0 1034.4096229335219
0.25 120.0 1056.3396102939134

0.30 40.0 820.48532442240912
0.30 50.0 864.81721193165276
0.30 60.0 903.01793306626575
0.30 70.0 936.77143987457748
0.30 80.0 967.13070171686991
0.30 90.0 994.80260583578638
0.30 100.0 1020.2860583598051
0.30 110.0 1043.9491920105042
0.30 120.0 1066.0705495008092

0.35 40.0 828.55397604267148
0.35 50.0 873.24971731819551
0.35 60.0 911.77188280323685
0.35 70.0 945.81542098750799
0.35 80.0 976.43920139491001
0.35 90.0 1004.3551308142532
0.35 100.0 1030.0670096356569
0.35 110.0 1053.9431809276018
0.35 120.0 1076.2647985870872
```

**Script:**

```
### heatmap with contour
reset session

FILE = "SO75041085.dat"

unset surface
set contour
set cntrparam levels discrete 930
set table $Contour
    splot FILE u 1:2:3
unset table
set surface
unset contour

set pm3d explicit
set pm3d map
set pm3d interpolate 0,0
set palette model RGB  defined ( 1.4 'black', 1.7 'blue', 2.0 'red', 2.1 'yellow')

set xlabel "{/Symbol a} [MeV]"
set ylabel "{/:Italic Bag} [MeV/fm^3]"
set cblabel "{/:Italic {{/Symbol e}/n_B }}[MeV]"

set size square
set xrange [0.0:0.35]
set yrange [40:120]
set mxtics 2
set mytics 2
set xtics 0.0,0.05,0.35
set key noautotitle

splot FILE u 1:2:3 w pm3d, \
      $Contour u 1:2:3 w l lt 8 lw 3 lc 'white' ti "930"
### end of script
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, that did the work :)

Comment: @martíncanullán glad to hear. Then please check the check mark at the top left of the answer indicating that the problem is solved.

Comment: one last thing how do i get the archive with the coordinates of the white curve?

Comment: @martíncanullán in the gnuplot console you can do `print $Contour` to get the numbers or you can plot it to a file: `set table "myContour.dat"; splot FILE u 1:2:3; unset table`.